# Two identical blur() calls, one works, one doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling two very similar `blur()` functions where one works and one doesn't.  The only difference between the two calls is literally the name of the `id`.  One is named **lighting-upgrade** and one is **hvac-upgrade**.  I cannot see a reason `id=lighting-upgrade` is working and `id=hvac-upgrade` is not.

The `<select>` in HTML:

```
<select id="lighting-upgrade" name="lighting">
  <optgroup>
    <option value="option1">Incandescent</option>
    <option value="option2">Fluorescent</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<input id="insulation-cost" type="number" name="insulation-cost">

<select id="hvac-upgrade" name="hvac">
  <optgroup>
    <option value="option1">RTU-80-Furnace</option>
    <option value="option2">RTU-92-Furnace</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<input id="lighting-cost" type="number" name="lighting-cost">
```

The constants I'm using:

```
 const lighting_upgrade = {
    option1: {type:"Incandescent", savings:0.1},
    option2: {type:"Fluorescent", savings:0.21}
};
const hvac_upgrade = {
  option1: {type:"RTU-80-Furnace", savings:0.1},
  option2: {type:"RTU-92-Furnace", savings:0.18}
};
```

The javascript call:

** this call works **

```
  $("#lighting-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = $("#lighting-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  = lighting_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
```

** this call does not works **

```
  $("#hvac-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = $("#hvac-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  = hvac_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
```

Using `console.log` this is the error I'm getting:

```
tool.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'savings')
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>
```

I'm not seeing the problem.

```js
const lighting_upgrade = {
    option1: {type:"Incandescent", savings:0.1},
    option2: {type:"Fluorescent", savings:0.21}
};

const hvac_upgrade = {
  option1: {type:"RTU-80-Furnace", savings:0.1},
  option2: {type:"RTU-92-Furnace", savings:0.18}
};

$(function() {
  $("#lighting-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = 
    $("#lighting-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  =
    lighting_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
    $("#result1").text(percent_savings);
  });
  
  $("#hvac-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = 
    $("#hvac-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  =
    hvac_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
    $("#result2").text(percent_savings);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span>Lighting:</span>
<select id="lighting-upgrade" name="lighting">
  <optgroup>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">Incandescent</option>
    <option value="option2">Fluorescent</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<input id="insulation-cost" type="number" name="insulation-cost">
<div id="result1">Lighting Result</div>
</div>
<div>
<span>HVAC:</span>
<select id="hvac-upgrade" name="hvac">
  <optgroup>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">RTU-80-Furnace</option>
    <option value="option2">RTU-92-Furnace</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<input id="lighting-cost" type="number" name="lighting-cost">
<div id="result2">HVAC Result</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet, and I don't see any problem.

Comment: Nothing is selected by default, and in that case `option_selected` would be undefined.  Right?

Comment: @Pointy - I edited the snippet to show the result in a `<div>`.  Lighting works.  HVAC returns the error I'm getting.

@Tim Roberts - Yes, that's true.  I forgot to add the empty option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working but you messed up the id of the element in your HTML. Here is updated snippet:

```js
const lighting_upgrade = {
    option1: {type:"Incandescent", savings:0.1},
    option2: {type:"Fluorescent", savings:0.21}
};

const hvac_upgrade = {
  option1: {type:"RTU-80-Furnace", savings:0.1},
  option2: {type:"RTU-92-Furnace", savings:0.18}
};

$(function() {
  $("#lighting-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = 
    $("#lighting-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  =
    lighting_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
    $("#result1").text(percent_savings);
  });
  
  $("#hvac-cost").blur(function() {
    var option_selected  = 
    $("#hvac-upgrade option:selected").val();
    var percent_savings  =
    hvac_upgrade[option_selected].savings;
    $("#result2").text(percent_savings);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span>Lighting:</span>
<select id="lighting-upgrade" name="lighting">
  <optgroup>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">Incandescent</option>
    <option value="option2">Fluorescent</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<!-- it was this HTML but in JavaScript code you used $('#lighting-cost')
<input id="insulation-cost" type="number" name="insulation-cost">
-->
<input id="lighting-cost" type="number" name="insulation-cost">
<div id="result1">Lighting Result</div>
</div>
<div>
<span>HVAC:</span>
<select id="hvac-upgrade" name="hvac">
  <optgroup>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">RTU-80-Furnace</option>
    <option value="option2">RTU-92-Furnace</option>
  <optgroup>
</select>
<!-- it was this HTML but in your JavaScript you use $('#hvac-cost');
<input id="lighting-cost" type="number" name="lighting-cost">
-->
<input id="hvac-cost" type="number" name="lighting-cost">
<div id="result2">HVAC Result</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it.  I stared right at it and didn't see it.  It was in the HTML.